# Lightswitch filter with multiple tables

Tags: lightswitch-2013

I am using lightswitch and I have a "Grid" with table A. Table A related to Table B and table b related to table C. Now how do I access data from table c using  Grid's PreprocessQuery or filter?

Answer (score 1):

You can expand each relationship in the query designer. Below I am creating a filter in the query designer on my `QuoteLines` table which has a relationship to my `Quotes` table which has a relationship to my `RepFirms` table which has a relationship to my `InsideSalesReps` table. You can filter on any data that is related to any of the linked tables.

[image: query designer]