# lightswitch multi-table query

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I'm new to LightSwitch. I have the following data:

1. tblContent.SubjectID
2. tblContent.SectionID
3. tblSection.SectionID
4. tblSection.SectionTitle
5. tblPageSection.SectionID
6. tblPageSection.PageID
7. tblPage.PageID
8. tblPage.PageTitle

I need to display all of the SectionTitle/PageTitle pairs for a particular SubjectID, which the user has selected on a previous page (so I'd be passing SubjectID as a parameter).

I have the obvious relationships set up between the tables in the database (joining on SectionID and PageID).

Can I do this using the LightSwitch query designer? I can't find any examples of using the LightSwitch query designer to join this many tables. If I can't use LightSwitch query designer, what is the best alternative approach?

I'm writing this for the HTML client, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29002375/lightswitch-filter-with-multiple-tables/29034649#29034649

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can either use a view if you have database access, or else create a custom WCF RIA service as described in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2011/04/08/how-do-i-display-a-chart-built-on-aggregated-data-eric-erhardt.aspx).